# Can't get ASP.Net MVC Edit Action to worth with my ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to use the following ViewModel

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public Project Project { get; set; } //bulk of the information
    public int SelectedGovernmentClientId { get; set; } //selected ID for the dropdown
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GovernmentClients { get; set; } //dropdown values
}
```

Here's my project class

```
public class Project
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    //omitting extra fields
    public virtual GovernmentClient GovernmentClient { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the action that I have

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ProjectViewModel projectViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //i am getting the following from debugging
        //projectViewModel.Project.GovernmentClient.Name is NULL
        //projectViewModel.Project.GovernmentClient.ID is the correct ID from the dropdown
        db.Entry(projectViewModel.Project).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(projectViewModel);
}
```

All the values are getting updated EXCEPT the government client. Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you debugged the code? What is the value of `projectViewModel.SelectedGovernmentClientId`? What is the value of `projectViewModel.Project.GovernmentClient` after you get the value from the DB?

Comment: `projectViewModel.SelectedGovernmentClientId` comes back with the selected value in the dropdown. `projectViewModel.Project.GovernmentClient`starts out as null, but contains the correct GovernmentClient object after the assignment

Comment: Is the entity attached to the context?

Comment: You're not actually setting GovernmentClient to a different value.  You are simply retrieving it, telling EF that you modified it, but didn't actually modify it.

Comment: @Kenneth, I am not sure what that means, sorry. I'll look into it.

Comment: @MystereMan, makes sense, but I added that line in an attempt to solve my problem. I am editing the code.

Comment: You're still not changing GovernmentClient.  You retrieve it from the database, then call SaveChanges without ever changing it.

Comment: @MystereMan Isn't that what this line is doing?

`projectViewModel.Project.GovernmentClient = db.GovernmentClients.Find(projectViewModel.SelectedGovernmentClientId);`

Comment: Added clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a whole day of playing around with this, I think I might've solved it

I added the following to my `Project` model

```
[ForeignKey("GovernmentClient")]
public int GovernmentClient_ID { get; set; }
```

To render the dropdown, I used this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Project.GovernmentClient_ID, Model.GovernmentClients)
```

To generate the `GovernmentClients` list, I used the following method

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetGovernmentClientsList(int selectedItem = -1)
{
    var defaultItem = Enumerable.Repeat(new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = "-1",
        Text = " - Select a government client - ",
        Selected = (selectedItem == -1)
    }, count: 1);
    var clients = db.GovernmentClients.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.ID.ToString(),
        Text = x.ClientName,
        Selected = (selectedItem == -1) ? false : (x.ID == selectedItem)
    });
    return defaultItem.Concat(clients);
}
```

Overall, I am happy with this, because I am not hardcoding any property names, which I know would come back and bite me.

Answer (score 1):

```
projectViewModel.Project.GovernmentClient = 
       db.GovernmentClients.Find(projectViewModel.SelectedGovernmentClientId);
```

You are retrieving the value from database and setting its state to modified. However, there is no modification at all.

Comment: My mistake, I added that line as an attempt to fix it. Code modified.